# Why find command failing from make file

Tags: windows, makefile, build, gnu-make

I am working on modifying a windows make file. The file, which is part of legacy build code has the following lines --

```
    WROOT := "MyBuild/win/Program Files/Windows Kits/10" 


   ROOT_SDK_Version := $(shell find $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include -maxdepth 1 -type d -path $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include/[0-9.]* )
```

The SHELL variable is mapped to bin/sh but when I print the variable ROOT_SDK_Version, it is empty. However, when I manually invoke the find command with the same arguments, it is giving the expected out.

To debug this issue, I modified above line in make file as below

```
ROOT_SDK_Version := $(shell find $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include -maxdepth 1 -type d -path $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include/[0-9.]* 2> output.txt )
```

And I see the contents of the file output.txt after running make -

```
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

So why is the find command failing when running from make file but is successful when I run it manually using the same arguments? Any pointers appreciated.

Providing more context-

WROOT_WIN10_SDK := "$(GOBUILD_CAYMAN_MSVC_DESKTOP_ROOT)/win/Program Files/Windows Kits/10"

The variable GOBUID...is== E:/Myscpetre20/depot/sim/sim-20fq1/build/gobuild/compcache/cayman_msvc_desktop/ob-11144741/windows2016-clean

So WROOT_WIN10_SDK is == "E:/Myscpetre20/depot/sim/sim-20fq1/build/gobuild/compcache/cayman_msvc_desktop/ob-11144741/windows2016-clean/win/Program Files/Windows Kits/10"

Comment: Immediately before the line `ROOT_SDK_Version := $(shell find ...` can you insert the line `$(info WROOT_WIN10_SDK=[$(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)])` to see what it prints.

Comment: it is printing this WROOT_WIN10_SDK=["E:/Myscpetre20/depot/sim/sim-20fq1/build/gobuild/compcache/cayman_msvc_desktop/ob-11144741/windows2016-clean/win/Program Files/Windows Kits/10" ]

Comment: I don't have a Windows system to play with at the moment, but I'll bet it has something to do with the quote marks and the space in `/Program Files/`.

Comment: Further to the comment by @Beta , the output from the `$(info ...` command appears to have a space between the final double quote `"` and the `]` character -- not sure if that's genuine or just an artifact.  If it's genuine then it's certainly a problem as `$(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)` and `/Include` will be treated as separate path arguments to `find`.

Comment: I think that is what causing the problem, but not sure why this is happening as I am defining it as WROOT_WIN10_SDK := "$(GOBUILD_CAYMAN_MSVC_DESKTOP_ROOT)/win/Program Files/Windows Kits/10",, without anyspace after the 10. Any ideas how to remove it

Comment: OK it is working now but not sure what did the trick, i removed the space between := and the trailing space at the end in the variable disappeared. Then I again added the space and still it is working now, so not sure what is coming to play here. But now , no space at the end of the variable and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the argument to the `-path` option needs to be quoted -- otherwise the glob `*` will be expanded by the shell rather than being passed to `find`.  So...

```
   ROOT_SDK_Version := $(shell find $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include -maxdepth 1 -type d -path '$(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)/Include/[0-9.]*' )
```

Comment: I tried that, now it says "find: /Include: No such file or directory". however I checked and printed that the variable $(WROOT_WIN10_SDK) is correctly populated

Comment: That suggests the variable `WROOT_WIN10_SDK` isn't being set the way you think in the makefile.  You need to provide more context.

Comment: Have updated my question to reflect how the variables are being set

Comment: Note that `$(WROOT_WIN10_SDK)` refers to a makefile variable.   If you're looking to use the environment variable, use `$$WROOT_WIN10_SDK`.   One idea to debug is to replace your `$(shell ...)`, with `$(info ... )` so you can see exactly what it's running.